# Searching the source code of a file generation generated during debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, file, search

In my visual studio solution, I have got 22 projects. when I build the solution, a text file is generated amongst other files in the debug folder of the startup project. Is there any way I can find the source code in these projects generating this particular file?

Comment: does it have a fixed name?

Comment: It may come from a custom MSBuild process. MSBuild processes can be customized in the _.csproj_ project files.

Comment: have you tried searching the whole solution?

Comment: @CédricBignon you may be right but in most cases the files generated by msbuild have random names.

Comment: yes, I just got the idea of searching it and I located the debug folder of other project containing this file. But this project has many source code files, so it is pretty difficult to know which code is actually generating this file.

Comment: have you tried searching in the solution; not in the folders?